# Re-indent for eruby files does not work

Tags: vimrc, indentation

I am trying to re-indent a `foo.html.erb` file, however when I do `gg=G` everything gets aligned to the beginning of the line. I couldn't figure out why that happens. I've tried installing polyglot or putting `eruby.vim` into `ftplugin` but none of them worked.

`:set filetype?` returns `filetype=eruby`

[image]

Here is my `.vimrc`:

```
set nocompatible              " be iMproved, required
filetype off                  " required

" set the runtime path to include Vundle and initialize
set rtp+=~/.vim/bundle/Vundle.vim
call vundle#begin()
" alternatively, pass a path where Vundle should install plugins
"call vundle#begin('~/some/path/here')

" let Vundle manage Vundle, required
Plugin 'VundleVim/Vundle.vim'

Plugin 'Valloric/YouCompleteMe'
Plugin 'bling/vim-airline'      " Lean & mean status/tabline for vim
Plugin 'vim-airline/vim-airline-themes'
Plugin 'tpope/vim-rails'
Plugin 'tpope/vim-bundler'
Plugin 'tpope/vim-surround'
Plugin 'tpope/vim-commentary'
Plugin 'flazz/vim-colorschemes'
" Plugin 'vim-syntastic/syntastic'
Plugin 'preservim/nerdtree'
Plugin 'ntpeters/vim-better-whitespace'
Plugin 'jiangmiao/auto-pairs'

" Markdown support
Plugin 'godlygeek/tabular'
Plugin 'plasticboy/vim-markdown'
" ----------------

" All of your Plugins must be added before the following line
call vundle#end()            " required
filetype plugin indent on    " required
" To ignore plugin indent changes, instead use:
"filetype plugin on
"
" Brief help
" :PluginList       - lists configured plugins
" :PluginInstall    - installs plugins; append `!` to update or just :PluginUpdate
" :PluginSearch foo - searches for foo; append `!` to refresh local cache
" :PluginClean      - confirms removal of unused plugins; append `!` to auto-approve removal
"
" see :h vundle for more details or wiki for FAQ
" Put your non-Plugin stuff after this line

filetype on
filetype plugin on
filetype plugin indent on

" " ------- Syntastic options -------

" set statusline+=%#warningmsg#
" set statusline+=%{SyntasticStatuslineFlag()}
" set statusline+=%*

" let g:syntastic_always_populate_loc_list = 1
" let g:syntastic_auto_loc_list = 1
" let g:syntastic_check_on_open = 0
" let g:syntastic_check_on_wq = 0

" " ----------------------------------

autocmd FileType ruby setlocal shiftwidth=2 ts=2
autocmd FileType yaml setlocal ts=2 sts=2 sw=2 expandtab

set ai
set encoding=utf-8

set number
set ruler
set relativenumber

set clipboard=unnamed

set autoindent
set expandtab
set shiftwidth=4
set softtabstop=4
set tabstop=4
set textwidth=120


set pastetoggle=<F10>
nmap <F6> :NERDTreeToggle<CR>

" Search settings
"=====================================================
set hlsearch

" Syntastic options
let g:syntastic_ruby_checkers = ['rubocop']

" CTRLP vim
set runtimepath^=~/.vim/bundle/ctrlp.vim
```

Comment: Welcome to [vi.se]! I think you've already seen this in the answer, but [Please don't post images of text](https://benknoble.github.io/blog/2019/11/24/pics-text/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your screenshot, all the lines which end with `%>` also start with `<%=`, except this one:

```
<= render 'shared/footer' %>
^^
✘
```

If you add a percent character between the leading `<` and the following `=`:

```
<%= render 'shared/footer' %>
 ^
 ✔
```

Then `gg=G` indents your file like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Trollo</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1">
    <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
    <%= csp_meta_tag %>

    <%= stylesheet_link_tag 'application', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload' %>
    <%= stylesheet_pack_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload' %>
  </head>

  <body>
    <%= render 'shared/navbar' %>
    <%= render 'shared/notices' %>

    <div class="container-fluid">
      <%= yield %>
    </div>

    <%= render 'shared/footer' %>

  </body>
</html>
```

---

Next time you have an issue:

- try to [post the code/data as a text which can be copied](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/303812/9780968); not as a screenshot; it's much easier to make tests against text
- try to [bisect your vimrc](https://github.com/chrisbra/vim_faq/blob/7f9c65c91d01e289a92b9e43a70ee2becadd66ce/vim_faq.txt#L1153-L1228)

Comment: Thank you so much. I was scratching my head over this for quite some time. Sorry for the image, I wanted to show how it looks but next time I will make sure to post the content as well.